# C++ WIN API : why I cant use WM_CREATE

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to learn Winapi to develop gui in c++ but I am having troubles with VM_CREATE My code til VM_CREATE works fine but code in case VM_CREATE doesnt work I am using visual studio 2017 And this is my code ::: (Visual studio gives no error ) Whats the problem

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>  



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

HWND textfield, hwnd, Button;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    MSG msg;
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"WindowClass", L"Window", WS_VISIBLE | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500,
        500,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (message)
    {

    case WM_CREATE:                     // WORKS TILL HERE
    textfield = CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"HELLO",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            300, 300, 100, 25,
            hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    Button = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON",L"Hello this is a button",
                WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                20,
                20,
                300,
                300,
                hwnd,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL);

    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Can you please elaborate? And please take some time to  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It doesnt work I meant it tho There is a windows titled as Windows and no text nor button

Comment: I suggest you read [this `WM_CREATE` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632619(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You should use the **hWnd** input in the callback for the static and button CreateWindow call rather than the global **hwnd**, which has not been set at the time that the WM_CREATE is called (WM_CREATE is called before CreateWindow returns)

So for the WM_CREATE part of the switch statement:

```
textfield = CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"HELLO",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
        300, 300, 100, 25,
        hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
Button = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON",L"Hello this is a button",
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
            20,
            20,
            300,
            300,
            hWnd,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL);
```

Comment: sry new to c++ can u send code

Comment: @GameplayerXd What is the first argument to your `WndProc` function? In the case of `WM_CREATE` it will be the window *being* created (the `CreateWindowEx` function you call in `WinMain` have not returned yet).

Comment: I solved it my problem by changing hwnd to hWnd but still thnx

It would be awsome if u upvote cause I am going to be banned from stackoverflow

Comment: Don't ask for upvotes. Also, you are expected to mark correct answers as such. Have you taken the [tour]?

Answer (score -1):

Add more parameters:

```
textfield = CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"HELLO",
                         WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                         300, 300, 100, 25,
                         hWnd, (HMENU)1, hInstance, NULL);
```

at least `hInstance` is important.

Comment: The instance handle is ignored for classes registered with the `CS_GLOBALCLASS` style. Standard controls (like a `"STATIC"` control) are registered as global. Passing `nullptr` in this case has the same effect as passing any other instance handle. See [What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873) for more information.